# NTILE alternative for non-uniformely distributed data sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a data set and want to display it, but it can be very huge (thousands of points), and I want to filter them. For example here is output for 1000+ points:
[image]

Now i use NTILE to get approximation, but it doesn't work as expexted if points are not distributed uniformly. And I get this output (NTILE with parameter 100):

[image]

How can I avoid this behaviour? SQL stored procedure is below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetSystemHealthCheckData]
    @DateFrom datetime,         
    @DateTo datetime,            
    @EstimatedPointCount int
    with recompile
AS

BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    set arithabort on

    if @DateFrom IS NULL
        RAISERROR ('@DateFrom cannot be NULL', 16, 1)

    if @DateTo IS NULL
        RAISERROR ('@DateTo cannot be NULL', 16, 1)     

    if @EstimatedPointCount IS NULL
        RAISERROR ('@EstimatedPointCount cannot be NULL', 16, 1)    

    ;With T as
    (
        SELECT *, GroupId = NTILE(@EstimatedPointCount) over (order by GeneratedOnUtc)
        FROM SystemHealthCheckData
        WHERE GeneratedOnUtc between @DateFrom AND @DateTo
    )

    SELECT  CpuPercentPayload = AVG(CpuPercentPayload),
            FreeRamMb = AVG(FreeRamMb),
            FreeDriveMb = AVG(FreeDriveMb),
            GeneratedOnUtc = CAST(AVG(CAST(GeneratedOnUtc AS DECIMAL( 18, 6))) AS DATETIME)
    FROM T
    GROUP BY GroupId
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: new approach

You might split your load with NTILE and then calculate an average for each group? I splitted my set in 4 groups. This lets the query come back with 4 average values. The number of groups could be calculated from the number of points you have or could be done fix.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, nmbr FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(5),(4.5),(4),(3.5),(3),(2.5),(2),(1.5),(1),(1.5),(1),(0.5),(0),(13),(2),(17),(5),(22),(24),(2),(3),(11);

SELECT tbl2.* 
      ,AVG(nmbr) OVER(PARTITION BY tbl2.tile)
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS tile
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)AS tbl2
```

If you want it reduced to the group values only you could try this

```
SELECT AVG(nmbr),tbl2.tile
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS tile
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)AS tbl2
GROUP BY tbl2.tile
```

--old text
You maybe want to think about a sliding average... In this example I tried to rebuild your values (long linear falling and wild jumping at the end). You can set the @pre and @post variables to set the grade of "flatening".

In short: There is an average calculated for each element and its direct neighbours.

Be aware of the fact that you must add an ORDER BY to avoid random results...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, nmbr FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(5),(4.5),(4),(3.5),(3),(2.5),(2),(1.5),(1),(1.5),(1),(0.5),(0),(13),(2),(17),(5),(22),(24),(2),(3),(11);

DECLARE @pre INT=3;
DECLARE @post INT=3;

SELECT tbl.*
      ,AvgBorders.*
      ,AvgSums.* 
      ,AvgSlide.*
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT tbl.id-@pre AS AvgStart
          ,tbl.id + @post AS AvgEnd
) AS AvgBorders
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(nmbr) AS CountNmbr
          ,SUM(nmbr) AS SumNmbr 
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    WHERE tbl.id BETWEEN AvgStart AND AvgEnd
) as AvgSums
CROSS APPLY
(
    select AvgSums.SumNmbr / AvgSums.CountNmbr As AvgValue
) As AvgSlide
;
```

Comment: Yes, it's about a sliding average, but problem that I don't know how many points should be grouped. For example "We should get 100 points from 01 april to 01 june that show dynamics". And data set has, for example, 113 points. And some algorithm like `Bresenham's line algorithm` is needed here to interpolate this data set.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy, You could calculate a "sliding deviation" first and add kind of a factor to your pre and post value. Thus you could narrow this intervall on heavy movements dynamically ... Please vote up and or mark as accepted if helpful, thx!

Comment: I upvoted but didn't mark it as answer yet: maybe there will be another one.

Comment: And i think it's not a "sliding average". It's more simple: we just split data on parts and get an average value from each window. We just should decide if THIS point is in THIS window or in the next one.

Comment: It works with points, not with period. In example below it should get something like `3 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3.7 1.7 4 3.5 4 3 2 1 0.5 0.5 0.5 1 2 3` ... We have no this zero points in data set, but we can see it on the plot. So if we want 100 result points we need split all plot on 100 equal intervals, get average value of points in each interval and return this interpolation as result. It's easy when `dataLength%numberOfLines == 0`, but it isn't when it's not true.